# Firebase crash reports are deobfuscated without line numbers

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Currently crash reports are shown as

Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
com.temp.app.Helper.convertToString (Helper.java:**(no line number here)**)
com.temp.app..fragment.FragmentEnterName$6.run (FragmentEnterName.java:**(no line number here)**)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5692)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)

but it should be like

Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
com.temp.app.Helper.convertToString (**Helper.java:25**)
com.temp.app..fragment.FragmentEnterName$6.run (**FragmentEnterName.java:15**)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5692)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)

I am using default proguard-android.txt  available in sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt

Content of config file is

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
#
# Starting with version 2.2 of the Android plugin for Gradle, these files are no longer used. Newer
# versions are distributed with the plugin and unpacked at build time. Files in this directory are
# no longer maintained.

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Proguard at all?  If so, can you edit your question to show your proguard config file?

Comment: @DougStevenson , I am using default proguard-android.txt available in sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt. As per your requirement I have copied the content of proguard content file.Please check it.Thanks

Comment: I don't think the default Proguard config should have the effect of removing line numbers from your app's classes, but Proguard can certainly do that if configured to do so.  Firebase has no reason to withhold line numbers, and it's clearly not doing so for platform classes.  So I wonder if there is some other config that could be stripping the line numbers from your app.

Comment: was an answer found for this? I'm testing different different crash reporting frameworks and this will be a killer for Firebase if they can't produce line numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your proguard config and it will add the line number in firebase:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Comment: And what if I want to keep the file names obfuscated... ?